# Android MediaPlayer seekTo with precision

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

Is there any workaround where I can use a long or double to seek a position in an audio file in Android? Currently seekTo takes only ints a parameters. I would like to be more precise (like within a tenth of a second)

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("music_file", "raw", getPackageName());
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, resID);
```

Currently:

```
mp.seekTo(5);
```

What I want is more precision:

```
mp.seekTo(5.2);
```

Comment: unit is milliseconds which is one thousandth of a second that is lowest precision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MediaPlayer.seekTo(int)` looks like it uses milliseconds as the parameter.

You need more precision than milliseconds? Or `MediaPlayer.seekTo(int)` is going to seconds instead of milliseconds?

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#seekTo%28int%29):

> public void seekTo (int msec)
>
> Seeks to specified time position. **Parameters** *msec*   the offset in
>   milliseconds from the start to seek to